# Emtpy messages when exporting data from Azure IoT Central to webhook

Tags: azure, export, iot, telemetry

I am following the guide below to try to export telemetry from IoT Central to a webhook.
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/iot-central/core/howto-export-data#DataExportFilters

I am testing with requestbin as the guide suggests. I do recieve message headers everytime new data arrives to the sensor, however the telemetry values are not recieved? I can read these in IoT Central, but they are not exported to the webhook?

[Screenshot from requestbin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSaOL.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Im facing the same, have u get a solution?